# Why I cant find readAllData() in my android studio project? I want to display data from my SQL database on recycler view. Which method should I use?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

{Cursor cursor = db.readAllData(); // compiler cant find this method}
I dont have any idea why I cant use it. When I write Cursor cursor = db.readAllData(); method got underlined red

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method in the platform. You have to implement one yourself in the class representing `db`.

Comment: I found solution. Thank you very much!!